# React get image from api using fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I need to get an image using the fetch api. My colleague said that the call to the server should return a base64 string to display the image. The image needs to be authenticated and I cant just use its url. This is what I have:

```
fetch(`${apiUrl}filestore/${logo.name}`, {
        
        .then(res => console.log(res)
```

Im not really sure how to get the base64 string. Apparantly im not using fetch right. Here is what is displayed in the console,
![screenshot image][1]

Comment: you need to use `.then(res => res.???()).then(body => ....)` where `???` can be one of `arrayBuffer`, `json`, `blob`, `formData` or `text` ... depending on how your server is sending the `body` of the response ... in the second `.then` you'll have some data

Comment: I guess the first thing you need to figure out is .. what is the server sending? raw data? a blob? base64 string? something else?

Comment: @JaromandaX apparently its sending a base64

Comment: @JaromandaX what is the proper type for base64?

Comment: in that case ... see the [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Examples) - oh, you did say blob .... use `res.text()` since base64 is just text

Comment: @JaromandaX the body in the second promise returns [object Promise] when I log it. How can I get the string from that?

Comment: did you do it like `.then(res => res.text()).then(body => console.log(body))` - i.e. res.text et al return a Promise ... so you chain another .then

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I did it exactly like that and the body is [object Promise]

Comment: you must've done something wrong ... because body won't be a promise if you do **exactly** that code, it can't be ... the actual body of a response can not be a Promise, such things as Promises are not able to be sent by a server - you must be console.log'ing something else - perhaps you think the code is the same, but it isn't

Comment: @JaromandaX fetch(`${apiUrl}filestore/${logo.name}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(''))
            ? `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('')).access_token}`
            : '',
        },
      })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(body => console.log(body));

Comment: there is no way that could output `[object Promise]`

Comment: @JaromandaX The exact line where Im console logging is printing [object Promise] to the console

Comment: what if you do `fetch('https://httpbin.org/get').then(res=>res.text()).then(body => console.log(body))` - exactly that URL, don't change anything - paste it in your browser console ... do you get `[object Promise]`?

Comment: @JaromandaX it also gives me a Promise {<pending>}. Then an object with values if i open it

Comment: this is in a browser? are you looking at the object returned by fetch rather than the value output by the console.log itself? (hint: I think you are) if you type `console.log('hello world')` you get what in your console?

Comment: I was having a similar problem to this recently when debugging in chrome. I don't know if maybe there's an issue with console logging the value from a fetch and multiple .then statements.

Can you try getting the code back to a state where it was returning `Promise {<pending>}` in the console? Assume that this is actually the string in base64 format and put it into a Text component somewhere.

`let base64;
fetch(url, options).then(res => res.text()).then(body => base64 = body);`

Try passing this base64 variable into the Text component.

What does it say when it's in a Text component?

Comment: Instead of a Text component, just put the base64 variable in a div (as you're not using react native, my bad)

Comment: From Developer Mozilla:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_your_own_request_object

Answer (score 0):

Try to format the res to json. Then check the res.

```js
fetch(`${apiUrl}filestore/${logo.name}`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Hidden'))
      ? `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Hidden')).access_token}`
      : '',
  },
})
.then(res => return res.json())
.then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: Changing to a json didnt solve it for me. Now I get an error 'the certificate to this server is invalid'

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Link to mdn documentation for Fetch API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
 .then(response => response.json()) 
 .then(data => console.log(data))
 .catch(e => console.log("error", e);
```

considering your response is of JSON type - Link to find the supported body instances - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body

Try console.log(typeof response); to find out what your response type is so you can set the body instance in .then(response => response.json() or response.text() etc.,)

Make sure you catch the error too.